# RC time constant in circuit with two caps with different potential

Tags: time-constant

I'm trying to develop a model for the switching speed of a MOSFET. In reducing the equivalent diagram I have come up with this circuit with a resistor and two capacitors in parallel.

[image]

The catch is that there is a different initial potential across one of the capacitors. How would you go about deriving a time-constant(s) from such a circuit?

The two voltages should be arbitrary even though they have values in the diagram.

The purpose is to establish which parameters influence the speed, and to derive a formula to determine the maximum speed from such parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [superposition](http://www.dummies.com/education/science/science-electronics/analyze-circuits-with-two-independent-sources-using-superposition/).  The total voltage at a given point is the sum of the voltage from each individual voltage source and current source in the circuit.

When calculating the contribution of a selected voltage or current source, other voltage sources are shorted and other current sources are left open.

For example, in the circuit below (from the link), Vo = Vo1 + Vo2 .

[image]

You should also add some series resistance to your model to get a physical result in the case where the 1.8V source is active and the 3.3V source is shorted.